# Download image on button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image in my page. I want the image to be downloaded when I click on a button. How can I do this using jQuery or Javascript? Kindly provide me with a fiddle. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/3EjUg/1/)

```
<div id="download">
    <img src="http://www.glamquotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/smile.jpg" id="image">
    <button id="dwnld"> Download image </button>
</div>
```

Comment: is the img.src the path tot he "full res" image? basically, is what they're viewing what they intend to download?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can actually do this with the HTML5 `download` attribute, if older browsers are an issue, you should use the serverside for this, and set the appropriate headers etc.

```
<a href="http://www.glamquotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/smile.jpg" download="smile.jpg">Download image</a>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3EjUg/5/)

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that attribute. Looking at MDN is says "when the user clicks on the link they will be prompted to save it as a local file". Funny thing was, in Chrome it just downloaded it without prompting me.

Comment: @j08691 - It does that for me to, not sure why chrome doesn't prompt the user, but at least it downloads. It's really neat as it's so simple to use as opposed to the serverside stuff where you have to set the content, the content disposition etc. in the header.

Comment: Absolutely. I'll have to remember that one. Thanks.

Comment: @adeneo Nice alternative!

Comment: op asked for "Download image on button click", but your answer only provides a solution for the `area`-tag not the `button`-tag

Comment: @InsOp - there is no `area` tag anywhere, the answer provided uses an anchor tag, and one would replace the button with that and if neccessary style the anchor as a button, or create the anchor programatically when the the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

save.php will return

"1|DOWNLOAD_NOS|FULL_PATH|FILE_NAME"
Or you may use jSON

```js
$('#save_wall').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"save.php",
    data: "id=<?=$_GET['id'];?>",
    success: function (dataCheck) {
      var m=dataCheck.split("|");
      if(m[0] == '1') {
        alert("Thank You for your Download Picture\n\nShortly Picture Download will start...");
        $('#save_wall_count').html(m[1]);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = m[2];
        a.download = m[3];
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
      }
      if(m[0] == '0') 
        alert("Error: Error in Save Picture or Not Found...\n\n"+ dataCheck);
    }
  });  
});
```