# how to download an image on click of button in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
$select_pic  = "SELECT pic.photo_link,od.* from orders as od inner join photo as pic ON pic.user_id = od.user_id WHERE od.id = '".$orderid."'";
$pic = $common->select_inner($select_pic);
foreach($pic as $photo){
}
```

I am getting images from this in $photo['photo_link'];
I want to download picture on click of download button how can i do this using php or javascript.

```
<a download="<?php echo $photo['photo_link']; ?>"  title="ImageName">
<img alt="ImageName" src="uploads/category/<?php echo $photo['photo_link']; ?>">
</a>
```

I have tried this but its not working

Comment: add `target="_blank"` also.

Comment: Did the image shows up in your `img` tag?

Comment: yes but its not clickable

Comment: I got my answer by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924238/download-image-on-button-click-using-jquery Thanks

Comment: If you need IE users to download image, you should have a look at [Content-Disposition](https://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml) HTTP header

Answer (score 1):

You are missing href attribute in tag.

I have checked with below code working:

```
<a href="" download="<?php echo $photo['photo_link']; ?>"  title="ImageName">
<img alt="ImageName" src="uploads/category/<?php echo $photo['photo_link']; ?>">
</a>
```

Please see following link for your reference: [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
<a href="uploads/category/<?php echo $photo['photo_link']; ?" download>
    <button>Download</button>
</a>
```